# Debian, DKIM and Exim4 never returns public key

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, email-server, exim, dkim

i wanted to use DKIM in an exam mailserver on debian.

My DNS settings are:

```
@                        IN TXT     "v=spf1 mx -all"
27564764._domainkey.example.com      IN TXT     "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCwQA5ED2afrQUFD9K7TBFLMtj74c9YAeKi+OCwBlCLT0fNexPT/23mTTtwEA1ykaSmYyx0Pxqzh7bkBAN4tKGsOtBSJB402RNurhhkEULpTelc5Gtvmxl8Iu2gQ7lvfnPqBM0x4ogVzKizTxnW0BVTffFsdUieVuHeGxmvZv3ODQIDAQAB"
```

Testing with this command:

```
host -t txt 27564764._domainkey.example.com
```

It always returns:

```
27564764._domainkey.example.com descriptive text "v=DKIM1"
```

My public key gets lost!?
Can anybody help me?

Thank You very much!!!

Comment: I used this tutorial: http://www.iodigitalsec.com/exim-dkim-and-debian-configuration/

Comment: You may need to split the record in parts due to it's length. Please approach your DNS service's documentation or support. (Except you manage your DNS server yourself)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found a solution, take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
Set a dot behind the domain:

```
27564764._domainkey.example.com.      IN TXT     "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=PUBLIC-KEY"
```

OR:
Remove the domain:

```
27564764._domainkey      IN TXT     "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=PUBLIC-KEY"
```

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution, but it makes no sense.  If DNS was having trouble LOCATING the record, it should have returned an NXDOMAIN (not found) type of error - not a neatly truncated result.

Comment: Yes, i don't understand it, too. But my hoster told me, if there is no dot at the end, the domain will be added automatically. So in my first try, i should have been able to get the right answer calling '27564764._domainkey.example.com.example.com descriptive text "v=DKIM1"' (add a second .example.com). So if i remove the first example.com or finish it with a dot, i should be right. That doesn't describe why i didn't get an error, but it solved my issue.